# How to call HTML view from XML view in sapui5

Tags: javascript, xml, routes, sapui5

I am designing a SAP UI5 Application which has 2 XML and 1 HTML view.I want to navigate to a HTML View from XML view on click of a button. How can i set routing for this.

Below code is not working:

```
routing: {
    config: {
        routerClass: "sap.m.routing.Router",
        viewType: "XML",
        viewPath: "executive.WebContent.view",
        controlId: "app",
        controlAggregation: "pages",

    },

    routes: [{
            "pattern": "",
            "name": "View1",
            "viewPath": "executive.WebContent.view",
            "viewType": "XML",
            "target": "View1"
        },
        {
            "pattern": "Login",
            "name": "View2",
            "viewPath": "executive.WebContent.view",
            "viewType": "XML",
            "target": "View2"
        },

        {
            "pattern": "Visitor",
            "name": "View3",

            "viewPath": "executive.WebContent.view",
            "viewType": "HTML",
            "target": "View3"


        }
    ],

    targets: {
        "View1": {
            "viewName": "Main"

        },
        "View2": {
            "viewName": "Login"

        },
        "View3": {
            "viewName": "Visitor"

        }
    }

}
```

Let me know, solution for this.

Comment: Move `viewType` to `targets`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65629199/5846045

Comment: For other readers: `HTMLView` is deprecated since SAPUI5/OpenUI5 1.108 ([`ef39784`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/ef397849ae0423ad758ca25ac45a16aa18afc789), [`2f98d40`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/2f98d407cd3752e6dcf1fc6e7938202c5db183cf))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I see you are defining a global type XML in the config part of your routing; this will cause a conflict in your routes.

I tried to do what you are trying to do right now. But, I found an alternative solution. You can have a third XML view and inside the XML you can embed your HTML view. something like this:

```
<mvc:HTMLView id="nestedViewhtmnl" 
viewName="executive.WebContent.view"
controller="executive.controller.xx" type="HTML"></mvc:HTMLView>
```

I hope this helps you =)

Comment: Thanks David for alternative solution but let me know, if there is direct solution (not workaround) for above issue

Comment: @JohnSmith https://stackoverflow.com/a/65629199/5846045

Answer (score 0):

1. All the target parameters you added to the `routes` are **deprecated** since 1.28!
2. According to the API reference, such parameters in `routes` are **ignored:**

   > All the deprecated parameters are ignored, if a `target` is used. [(Source)](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.core.routing.Route#constructor)

I.e. do **not** use `viewName`, `viewType`, `viewPath`, etc.. in `routes` but **move them to the `targets`.**
Cf. also https://stackoverflow.com/a/72617737/5846045 for proper routing configuration.

```json
{
  "routing": {
    "config": {
      "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
      "path": "executive.WebContent.view",
      "viewType": "XML",
      "type": "View",
      "controlId": "app",
      "controlAggregation": "pages",
      "async": true
    },
    "routes": [
      {
        "...": "...",
        "target": "myTarget"
      }
    ],
    "targets": {
      "myTarget": {
        "name": "NotXML",
        "viewType": "HTML*",
        "...": "..."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- [API reference: `sap.ui.core.routing.Route`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.core.routing.Route#constructor)
- [API reference: `sap.ui.core.routing.Router`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.core.routing.Router)

---

* HTML views and HTML fragments are deprecated since UI5 1.108!